# ConstraintAnnotations of jersey 2 don't work

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I followed steps from [Jersey User Guide - bean-validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#bean-validation), and add below to pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I tried to use constraint annotation in the API

```
@Path("shows")
public Response getShows(
        @NotNull @QueryParam("cid") Long cid,
        @Valid @QueryParam("sort_by") @ValidSortBy(modalClass=Show.class) List<String> sortBy,
        @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue("100") @Max(1000) int limit,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo
)
```

But both @NotNull and @Max don't work when http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/shows?limit=10001 is called. I don't know the reason, then I tried to custom a validator called @ValidSortBy(used for parameter 'sortBy')

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidSortByValidator.class)
public @interface ValidSortBy {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    Class<? extends BaseModal>[] modalClass() default {};
}

public class ValidSortByValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidSortBy, List<String>> {
    Class<? extends BaseModal> modalClass;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidSortBy annotation) {
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaa initialize");
        if (annotation.modalClass().length > 0) {
            modalClass = annotation.modalClass()[0];
            System.out.println(modalClass.getTypeName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> sortBy, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But there even isn't any output.

Can anyone tell me the reason? Thank you a lot!

The resourceConfig is initialized like this and there isn't web.xml

```
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();

resourceConfig.packages([package names]);
resourceConfig.property("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", true);
resourceConfig.property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);

registerResourceConfig(resourceConfig); // register some error mappers

ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);

servletHolder.setInitOrder(1);
servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.tracing", "ALL");

ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContextHandler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");

servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

addServletFilters(servletContextHandler);

return servletContextHandler;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by register validation manually. Below code is added in registerResourceConfig

```
resourceConfig.register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationFeature.class);
```

Comment: I can't find any place that disables this feature, but registered manually does work.